# How to set value to fields of List item getting values from the folder that it is in?

Tags: 2007, lookup-column

I have some folders with some properties(Name of project, Project Number and etc.) When I create a item inside of this folder I need to fill out these information again for the item.

I would like to get them from the folder's properties. Is it possible in Sharepoint 2007?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using Event handlers. Look for ItemAdded/ItemUpdated event handlers.

Comment: Thanks Nadeem,Do you have any example by chance?

Comment: Following are some of the useful liks which show how to create even handlers: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407274(v=office.14).aspx http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/40e97e/sharepoint-2010-lists-and-event-handlers/ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms437502(v=office.14).aspx